# Is there a way to make foreign key from an attribute to another from other class in django?

Tags: python, html, django

```
class Assignatura(models.Model):

    """docstring for Assignatura"""

    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 40)

    codi = models.IntegerField()

    any_academic = models.CharField(max_length = 7)



class Matricula(models.Model):

    """docstring for Matricula"""

    nia_alumne = models.ForeignKey(Alumne, null = False,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Nom alumfne')

    codi_assignatura = models.ForeignKey(Assignatura, null = False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    any_academic = models.CharField(max_length = 7)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="matriculas", null=True)
```

i Want that codi_assignatura gets only codi from Assignatura

Comment: Are `codi` unique in the `Assignatura`?

Comment: Yes there is only one codi for each Assignatura

Comment: What do you mean "gets only codi from Assignatura" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `code` field of the `Assignatura` unique:

```
class Assignatura(models.Model):
    """docstring for Assignatura"""
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    codi = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    any_academic = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

If the target field is unique, then you can specify a [**`to_field=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) in the `ForeignKey`:

```
class Matricula(models.Model):
    """docstring for Matricula"""
    nia_alumne = models.ForeignKey(Alumne, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Nom alumfne')
    codi_assignatura = models.ForeignKey(Assignatura, to_field='codi', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    any_academic = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="matriculas", null=True)
```

Now the `codi_assignatura_id` field will store the `code` of the `Assignatura` to which it is referring.